# Is there risk importing data with auto increment id #'s that are higher than the current numbers?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have to import data into a new database.  That new database already has a small set of data.  I have two large tables I need to import in there.

Is there any risk of a higher `id` getting over written or causing problems later as new data comes in?

This is the current setup of the database tables.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

**Table** `websites`

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `url` (
      `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `userid` int(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `alias` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `special` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
      `website` text NOT NULL,
      `city` text NOT NULL,
      `story` text NOT NULL,
      `date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `click` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `meta_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `ads` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `bundle` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
      `public` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `archived` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `type` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=127878 ;
```

**Table** `statistics`

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scores` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `shorr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `curlid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `curluserid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `website` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `referal` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1807671 ;
```

Comment: your old table also has the same structure?

Comment: They have the same structures.

Comment: and the ids on the old table does not overlap the ids in new table?

Comment: None of the ids overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you insert the data in new table, your next `auto_increment` value will be `Max(id) + 1`. Which means if you insert new row, the id given will be highest number in the id column.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744818/reset-mysql-auto-increment-when-a-large-number-already-exists) may be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 3):

1. `LOAD` the new data into a separate table (`staging`), without including the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field.
2. Decide whether there are any duplicates that need to be avoided.
3. `INSERT ... SELECT` (without id) to copy the "new" data into the real table.
4. `DROP TABLE staging;`

Comment: More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table